# Unable to SELECT form DB with ORDER BY and php IF

Tags: php, mysql

i use following to statement to load data form `SQL` the SELECT query works well until `php` IF is executed.

i want to use 2 `ORDER BY` in single statement when if statement is executed i get

> Fatal error : Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND sca IN (?)'
>   at line 1' in
>   C:\Users\Amin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\fetch.php:34 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 C:\Users\Amin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\fetch.php(34): PDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM a...') #1 {main} thrown in
>
> C:\Users\Amin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\fetch.php on line 34

How do i solve this problem

```
if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM allpostdata WHERE sts = '1' AND mca='Vehicle' ORDER BY pdt DESC";

if (!empty($_POST['cate'])) {
    $query .= " AND sca IN (" . str_repeat("?,", count($_POST['cate']) - 1) . "?)";
} else {
    $_POST['cate'] = []; // in case it is not set 
}

if (!empty($_POST['brand'])) {
    $query .= " AND product_brand IN (" . str_repeat("?,", count($_POST['brand']) - 1) . "?)";
} else {
    $_POST['brand'] = []; // in case it is not set 
}

if (!empty($_POST['model'])) {
    $query .= " AND mdl IN (" . str_repeat("?,", count($_POST['model']) - 1) . "?)";
} else {
    $_POST['model'] = []; // in case it is not set 
}

if (!empty($_POST['sort'])) {
    if ($_POST["sort"][0] == "ASC" || $_POST["sort"][0] == "DESC") { //simplistic whitelist
        $query .= " ORDER BY prs " . $_POST['sort'][0];
    }
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$params = array_merge($_POST['cate'], $_POST['brand'], $_POST['model']);
$stmt->execute($params);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
$total_row = $stmt->rowCount();
$output = '';
```

Comment: A MySQL query has a specific [syntax order](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html). The `ORDER BY pdt DESC` in the initial query is messing everything up.

Comment: @aynber so what is the solution?

Comment: Add it at the end after all of your IF statements.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you dumped the generated SQL query to see whether its valid or not?

Comment: @NicoHaase yes i tried here is the dumped SQL`SELECT * FROM allpostdata WHERE sts = '1' AND mca='Vehicle' ORDER BY pdt DESC, prs ASC` **this part in Query** , prs ASC last if statement

Comment: That does not look like the output of the given code.  There is **no way** that the given code could produce that query, as there is only one occurence of `prs` and that is directly after `ORDER BY`

Comment: @NicoHaase am following this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59202659/4826112 answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by @aynber, the order by should be the last clause in your query. Thus, the correct form would be as below:

```
if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM allpostdata WHERE sts = '1' AND mca='Vehicle'";

if (!empty($_POST['cate'])) {
$query .= " AND sca IN (" . str_repeat("?,", count($_POST['cate']) - 1) . "?)";
} else {
$_POST['cate'] = []; // in case it is not set 
}

if (!empty($_POST['brand'])) {
$query .= " AND product_brand IN (" . str_repeat("?,", count($_POST['brand']) - 1) . "?)";
} else {
$_POST['brand'] = []; // in case it is not set 
}

if (!empty($_POST['model'])) {
$query .= " AND mdl IN (" . str_repeat("?,", count($_POST['model']) - 1) . "?)";
} else {
$_POST['model'] = []; // in case it is not set 
}
$query .= " ORDER BY pdt DESC";
if (!empty($_POST['sort'])) {
if ($_POST["sort"][0] == "ASC" || $_POST["sort"][0] == "DESC") { //simplistic whitelist
    $query .= ", prs " . $_POST['sort'][0];
}
}
```

Comment: Can you echo your query before ending the if and share.

Comment: `" ORDER BY pdt DESC"` works but `if (!empty($_POST['sort']))` doesn't work

Comment: That might have been caused by a missing semicolon (;) I have added it now. Can you check again?

Comment: i added semicolon before this query doesn't work `SELECT * FROM allpostdata WHERE sts = '1' AND mca='Vehicle' ORDER BY pdt DESC, prs ASC` **this part in Query** `, prs ASC` last if statement

Comment: What is the error that you are getting while executing the mentioned query?

Comment: I don't get any error `, prs ASC` does nothing i tried with `DESC` too but `SELECT * FROM allpostdata WHERE sts = '1' AND mca='Vehicle' ORDER BY  prs ASC` this works

Comment: why can't this `SELECT * FROM allpostdata WHERE sts = '1' AND mca='Vehicle' ORDER BY pdt DESC, prs ASC` here **pdt is date `pdt DATETIME`** and **prs is price prs decimal(10,0) `**